# Call a function in silverlight application from a c# application

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have a .NET application which has a `WebBrowser` hosted within it. On the page that the browser is currently displaying is a Silverlight application.

I've looked at the Siverlight binaries in ILSpy and found the function I wish to call.

I'm guess security with prevent me from doing this, but I thought I'd ask anyways, is this possible?

Comment: Wow... You might want to break this question down... Start with "How do I locate Silverlight assemblies in cache" and go with that as a starter. P.S. Silverlight output is a `XAP` file, this in reality is a zip archive where you would find the "assemblies".

Comment: @Belogix - sorry edited.

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible. Silverlight applications can only reach out to webservices and do not directly interact with the OS except for limited file access.